# How do I find $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to0}(x^2+y^2)\sin\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)$

Tags: limits

As the title suggested ,I am kinda stuck at this limit.I tried the following :

-We know that
$$-1\le \sin\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)\le1$$

when $xy!=0$.

-From here I tried to use a squeeze rule so I multiplied by $x^2+y^2$ thus having 
$$(x^2+y^2)\le(x^2+y^2) \sin\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)\le(x^2+y^2)$$

But limit of $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to 0}x^2+y^2=0$ ; the same goes for its counterpart. So if the two limits are $0$ then our desired limit is also $0$.

Is this wrong?
If so could you please give me an alternate solution?

Comment: This is correct and there is no need for any alternate solution.

Comment: Use mathjax. [Click on this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: As I am new to this website ,I didn't know about these rules of formatting my question. Will use in my future posts.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof and answer is correct. But, even though this is probably just a typo, on the step where you multiplied all parts of the inequality by $x^2+y^2$, you forgot to put a negative sign in front of the first part. You put $(x^2+y^2)$, but for the first part, it should be $-x^2-y^2$, or $-(x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1802439)

Comment: Okay, thank you, I will do that next time!